# Same name inserting again and again in the the dropdown list when click on tab button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using my function in `onclick nav tabs event` (when click on any tab this below function activates). I just want that no same name can twice be inserted into the dropdownlist. Below function is working just perfectly. I just need a check maybe like `name.text != arr[i]` something like that to prevent it to insert the same name twice in the list. Any help would be appreciated.

**js:**

```
<script>
$(".nav-tabs li").click
(
    function()
    {
        var getnumber = document.getElementById("permanentno").value;
        var getData = 'methodname=getList&no='+getnumber;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Dropdown List/List.php',
            data: getData,
            success: function(resp)
            {
                alert(resp); // names for example: mile,stone,
                var arr = resp.split(",");

                var list = $(".dropdownlist");

                var html = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    var name = arr[i];
                    if(name.length != 0)
                    {
                        html += "<option value='" + name + "'>";
                        html += name;
                        html += "</option>";
                    }
                }
                $(".dropdownlist").append(html);
            }
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append options to the `dropdownlist` on the loop, and check repeated names using jQuery like:

```
var list = $(".dropdownlist");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var name = arr[i];
    if (name.length != 0 && !list.find("option[value='" + name + "']").length) {
        var html = "<option value='" + name + "'>";
        html += name;
        html += "</option>";
        list.append(html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could keep track of the names with another array and [IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Note that for IE<9 support you'll need a shiv to use it.

```
var names = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var name = arr[i];
                if(name.length != 0 && names.indexOf(name) == -1)
                {
                    html += "<option value='" + name + "'>";
                    html += name;
                    html += "</option>";
                    names.push(name);
                }
            }
```